# Keyboard preferences are lost after each restart

Tags: macos, keyboard, preferences

I had this strange behaviour on my Mac running OS X my Mac running OS X El Capitan 10.11.6.

When logging in, I have the following keyboard shortcut conflict between Spotlight and keyboard layout switcher:

[image: Enabled keyboard shortcut]

After disabling it, conflict disappears:

[image: Disabled keyboard shortcut]

But if I restart my Mac, the configuration was reset back to first step.

Same problem if I changed the keyboard shortcut: It was reset to default configuration after any restart, whatever the shortcut.

What is happening and why OS X isn't able to keep my keyboard preferences?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I indicate here two solutions because the problem may be caused by either :

- ownership
- plist file

## Ownership problem

To troubleshoot my problem, I opened a Terminal and tried to find which configuration file had a problem:

```
cd Library/Preferences
ls -l com.apple.*
```

And in the middle of all my `com.apple.*` files I found one owned by root:

```
-rw-------   1 myuser  staff      485 19 jan  2018 com.apple.speech.voice.prefs.plist
-rw-------   1 myuser  staff      107 22 jan  2018 com.apple.suggestions.plist
-rw-------   1 root    wheel     2644 11 apr  2018 com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist
-rw-------   1 myuser  staff      110 12 oct 10:00 com.apple.syncserver.plist
-rw-------   1 myuser  staff     1862 26 nov 14:04 com.apple.systempreferences.plist
```

So I thought is was not normal. Using `find`, I tried to see if there were other files owned by root:

```
$ find ~/Library/Preferences -user root
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist
```

But it was the only one.

So I just changed ownership:

```
chown myuser ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist
```

And restarted my computer to verify: bingo !

It was an ownership problem that prevented macOS to save my keybord shortcut preferences.

## PList file

Sometimes, System Preferences pane could not keep some options after a restart (e.g. Keyboard visualizer and symbol visualizer).

### For shortcut problems

Back up and then remove the `com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist` file.

Reboot

*This file seems to keep information of `Shortcut`'s section in System Preferences pane.*

### For Keyboard Visualiser / Symbol Visualizer problems

Back up and then remove the `com.apple.HIToolbox.plist` file.

Reboot

*This file seems to keep information of `Keyboard`'s section in System Preferences pane.*

Comment: Thank you, you save my life!